# What trim material can be used around a 6" circular permanent hole in drywall?

Tags: drywall, trim

I need to make a 6" circular hole in a wall that goes between a room and a walk-in closet for a portable air conditioning pipe.  It is in a basement and the pipe needs to be exposed spiral (like in a commercial application) because I don't have room for soffits (ceiling low + other space issues) and I want to be able to take it off for painting etc.  The framing is regular 2x4 studs.  So I would have a 6" hole on the room side sheet and one on the closet side.  I would prefer if it were not just a hole in drywall, however exactly cut, but if there was some sort of insert inside it that trims it nicely.

Any idea if there is a ready product like this or that can be ordered and, if not, how would I go about fabricating one?  Imagine a round window without the window glass part, just a hole trim.

Comment: a bit of string and a pencil will help a bit

Answer (score 1):

You could use a 6" hole saw that can be used to cut holes for recessed light cans. These can be found at any big box hardware store. After that if you wanted to trim it up you could use a 6" recessed can trim and baffle. These can be bought for under 10$ at any big box store as well. These usually attach with springs but i would think you could screw it to the drywall or even use a construction adhesive.

Comment: I think the hole needs to be a tad larger in diameter than the pipe itself, which is 6", so I doubt a standard size product would fit the bill

Comment: you can try a 6 3/8" hole saw maybe use the flexible drywall bead and then mud it.

Comment: cutting is not a problem.  finding trim is